# Как вернуть из метода коллекцию

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть задание в котором нужно написать метод,  который будет принимать массив и возвращать количество и отсортированную коллекцию уникальных элементов. Я решил просто использовать коллекцию TreeSet так как она гарантирует уникальное множество и сама отсортирует массив. Но у меня возникла проблема. Как правильно нужно выводить саму коллекцию и как в строке `mySet.addAll(arr)` можно добавить все элементы из массива в коллекцию не используя цикл

```java
    public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {5,7,8,7,8,23,22,23,31,35,31,40,41,40,40};

        System.out.println(numUnique(list));

    }

public static int numUnique(int[] arr){
          TreeSet<Integer> mySet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
          for( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
              mySet.add(arr[i]);
          }
          mySet.addAll(arr); // альтернативный вариант, что бы не использовать цикл
          return mySet.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: перед добавления массива в набор можно использовать [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)). Для преобразования коллекции в строку посмотри [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/5122436)

Comment: Не совсем понял. Мне нужно просто созадть коллекцию в которую присвоить метод Array.asList(arr) с параметром массива ,вот так ? ```TreeSet<Integer> mySet = Arrays.asList(arr);```

Comment: нет. `addAll` принимает коллекцию -- например, лист. Но массив не принимает. Поэтому преобразуй массив в лист.

Comment: За место таких костылей, советую использовать `List list = List.of​(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);`. И за место циклов, вы можете просто передать в конструктор `new TreeSet<Integer>(list);`

Comment: Сначала определиться что с чем делать. Для того чтобы использовать `addAll` ,нужно смотреть на тип передаваемого аргумента, и если он не соответствует сигнатуры метода, то использовать адаптер. Пример [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099119/573032), а для вывода коллекции можно создать переменную, которой будет пользоваться метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если функционально :

```
public static List<Integer> numUnique(final int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Можно так, в этом случае метод принимает любые числа, им же типизирует результат:

```
public <T extends Number> List<T> numUnique(final T[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Если вы можете принимать в аргументах не int[], а Integer[] , то можно еще так :

1) если у вас Java9+ то у интерфейса Set появились статические методы для инициализации (паттерн фабричный метод) , посему можно так можно :

```
return new TreeSet<>(Set.of(arr))
```

2) ну, а если версия Java9 ниже, чем указанная, и функциональный подход вам не по душе, то так:

```
return new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Comment: @Артём читайте ответ внимательней : Если вы можете принимать в аргументах не int[], а Integer[] , то можно еще так . вы в аргументах принимаете массив примитивов (int[]), а этот метод работает для массива ссылочного типа (Integer[]). для примитивов я предложил вам функциональное решение

Comment: Понял. А если мне к примеру нужно создать такой же метод , но который может принимать массив значений любого ссылочного числового типа , как вообще это реализовать ?

Comment: @Артём ответ дополнил. мало того, если вы <T extends Number> измените на <T>, то метод будет принимать вообще любой массив ссылочного типа (не только для чисел).

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно **указать** в описании метода [тип возвращаемого значения](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.17.php)
Например :

```
public static TreeSet<Integer> numUnique(int[] arr){}
```

*void - ничего не возвращает.*